# Google Maps API v3 & easy methods of generating KML coordinates for overlays?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been looking around the google maps documentation and examples and would like to know if there is an easy method of generating coordinates for a state or country etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for shape files in various formats for all kinds of features, you can have a look at the [Natural earth data](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) dataset. It is also available on [Google Fusion Tables in different formats](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2011/02/natural-earth-vectors-in-cloud.html).